# Reading information from yaml document

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to access the map information from map.yaml . Can I use the basic C++ file handling to read all the fields from the file? I tried using yaml-cpp but its instructions were clumsy and even if there were no compiler errors, I could not get rid of dereferencing errors during run time. Is there a tutorial on ROS to demonstrate how to read map data from yaml file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194774/reading-information-from-yaml-document/) by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2014-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this [topic](http://answers.ros.org/question/12321/how-to-write-and-parse-yaml-file-for-ros/) can help you to solve your problem. But if I were you I would be more specific. I have many programs with reading yaml files, but from your question I don't understand very well yur problem.

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2014-10-13**:
My code is working now. And the dereferencing error was because I was passing a wrong argument as file name.